# Jquery DatePicker Custom Buttons

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Iam using display Jquery datepicker as inline like this

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

when i am trying to add custom buttons on buttonpane, Buttons are not getting dispalyed...when i replaced inline datepicker to default datepicker, i.e dispaly on textfield custom buttons are dispalyed.

Please give me some idea how to display custom buttons when display as inline datepicker.

iam using following code for display custom buttons

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    beforeShow: function (input) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var buttonPane = $(input)
                .datepicker("widget")
                .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");

            var btn = $('<button class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">Clear</button>');
            btn.unbind("click")
            .bind("click", function () {
                $.datepicker._clearDate(input);
            });

            btn.appendTo(buttonPane);

        }, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: The inline datepicker lacks some things we need to run the beforeShow.

Before running your code you need to extend the datepicker with the code posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961963/beforeshow-event-not-firing-on-jqueryui-datepicker

With that the beforeShow will work but the .datepicker("widget") code of a inline datepicker return emtpy, so you cannot modify it.