# Wrap calendar table of jQuery-ui inline datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have created an [inline calendar](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline) using jQuery-ui datepicker plugin.
But the container is narrower than the calendar. So I need a solution that user can scroll the calendar, while datepicker header will remain unscrollable. So I want to wrap the table with a div. But "[beforeshow](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow)" is not working in this case.

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function() {
        $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').wrap('<div class="calendar-wrap"></div>');
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE link](http://jsfiddle.net/armikbd/PrFX2/)

## expected output:

[image]

Comment: Finally I got [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12286320/3377130) that enables me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function ($) {
    $.extend($.datepicker, {
        _generateHTML_original: $.datepicker._generateHTML,
        _generateHTML: function (inst) {
            var $html = $(this._generateHTML_original(inst));
            return $($html[0]).prop('outerHTML') +
                   $('<div class="calendar-wrap"></div>').html($html[1]).prop('outerHTML');
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```