# Set selected data in datepicker after click

Tags: jquery, get, datepicker, set, selected

I'm using datapicker jQuery. After select date one time, I want to make calendar show **selected date** not **current date**. This is my step, and need to know how I can do **No. 5**

1. Click button
2. Show Datapicker. ( It shows current date **2015-02** )
3. Choose **2015-01**, then automatically date set in textbox.
4. Click button again.
5. Show Datapicker. ( **It shows current date again not 2015-01...** )

#### code.

```
    $(function () {
            $('#MainContent_txtMonth').datepicker({
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm',
                showMonthAfterYear: true,
                monthNamesShort: ['1월','2월','3월','4월','5월','6월','7월','8월','9월','10월','11월','12월'],
                showOn: "button",
            }).focus(function () {
                var thisCalendar = $(this);
                $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
                $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function () {
                    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    thisCalendar.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried beforeShow function of date picker on textfield.

for more detail on beforeShow: [beforeShow](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow)

Comment: I checked. but I think can't use this method well.. @TechnoCrat could you give me example using beforeshow? >> Function( Element input, Object inst )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961963/beforeshow-event-not-firing-on-jqueryui-datepicker

Comment: Hmm... thanks @TechnoCrat , but it's not what I want. :) I want to show selected date after click.