# How to highlight certain dates in jquery datepicker WITHOUT using beforeShowDay?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is there any other way to highlight certain dates from an array on an inline datepicker calendar other than using beforeShowDay()? beforeShowDay doesn't work for me. It only changes the color of today's date and doesn't highlight any other dates. I would like an alternative using jquery or javascript. For what is worth, here my code below

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
beforeShowDay : function (date){
json.events.forEach(function (jsondate,counter) {

//get jquery date
var jquerydate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date);


//get date busy with events
var busyday = jsondate.date;

if (jquerydate === busyday) {

console.log ('event date :' +busyday);//print all dates busy with events works here

return [true, '.event-highlight', 'tooltip text'];//BUT only highlight today's date
           
}else{
return [true, '', ''];
}

});
return [true];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I was facing has everything to do with how `beforeShowDay` function is setup to basically fire after the calendar is being displayed. It renders before anything. So if you have it inline where it's always displayed you might run into display issues like myself. This issue was addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961963/beforeshow-event-not-firing-on-jqueryui-datepicker) and also [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/inline-datepicker-beforeshow-not-occurring) on the jquery forum on long time ago. But I do want to post an answer complementary to that fix here.

html

```
<div id="calendar_datepicker"></div>//inline not an input
```

js

```
function myCalendar() {

//before show day fix for inline calendar
$.extend($.datepicker, {

// Reference the orignal function so we can override it and call it later
_inlineDatepicker2: $.datepicker._inlineDatepicker,

// Override the _inlineDatepicker method
_inlineDatepicker: function (target, inst) {

// Call the original
this._inlineDatepicker2(target, inst);

var beforeShow = $.datepicker._get(inst, 'beforeShow');

if (beforeShow) {
beforeShow.apply(target, [target, inst]);
}
}
});

//calendar
$('#calendar_datepicker').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
todayHighlight: true,

beforeShow: function( input, inst ) {

console.log(input);

},

});
}
```

> console.log(input) returns a node containing the date value

> console.log(inst) returns an object with month, year and day

**Object result**

```
{
  "id": "calendar_datepicker",
  "input": {
    "0": {},
    "length": 1
  },
  "selectedDay": 14,
  "selectedMonth": 0,
  "selectedYear": 2021,
  "drawMonth": 0,
  "drawYear": 2021,
  "inline": true,
  "dpDiv": {
    "0": {},
    "length": 1
  },
  "settings": {
    "dateFormat": "yy-mm-dd",
    "changeMonth": true,
    "changeYear": true,
    "todayHighlight": true
  },
  "currentDay": 14,
  "currentMonth": 0,
  "currentYear": 2021,
  "yearshtml": null,
  "_keyEvent": false
}
```